# what's the outcome of select *, count(*) from aTable

Tags: select, aggregate-functions

Wonder what would happen if i select both * and an aggregate together.

Will it be just one row or multiple rows?

example:

```
select *, count(*) from employee
```

Comment: Which database engine? You could also always try it out quickly.

Comment: The outcome is an error message. This is illegal SQL.